# WAL log files fill up quickly - how to prevent this?

Tags: config, arangodb, rocksdb

currently the logs in the folder “/engine-rocksdb/journals” are running full (WAL logs).

When does ArangoDB do a cleaning run of these logs and delete them automatically and how to trigger this cleaning run earlier? My ArangoDB 3.10 runs in single mode and in a virtual environment (cloud with a network storage).

The logfile are increasing very fast for me because there are many writes to the DB. What is the best way, any idea?

What I have done so far:

If I set the value “rocksdb.wal-archive-size-limit” it does delete the logs when the set limit is reached, but it shows errors in the logfile:

`2022-09-27T17:53:04Z [898948] WARNING [d9793] {engines} forcing removal of RocksDB WAL file '/archive/813371.log' with start sequence 5387062892 because of overflowing archive. configured maximum archive size is 1073741824, actual archive size is: 75401520`

However, I still don't understand the meaning of the logfile output: "configured maximum archive size is 1073741824, actual archive size is: 75401520`". The "actual archive size" is smaller?

But what are the consequences of lowering the "wal-archive-size-limit" value? Is it possible to switch off the wal-archive completely. What exactly is it for? As I understand it, ArangoDb need it for transaction security (i.e. in case of power loss), right?

In general, yes, this is a good thing, but how can I get ArangoDb to a) limit this WAL-archive (without error massages) and b) do a cleaning run faster?

thx :-)

Answer (score 4):

> When does ArangoDB do a cleaning run of these logs and delete them automatically and how to trigger this cleaning run earlier?

ArangoDB uses RocksDB underneath, and RocksDB will move WAL file (.log files) into its archive as soon as possible. In order to do so all data from the WAL file needs to be safely stored in the column families' .sst files and have been flushed to disk.
ArangoDB will delete files from the WAL archive (and only from there) once it can assure that an archived WAL file is not used anymore. It will not remove files for the archive that are or may be in current use.

There are a few reasons why ArangoDB may keep archived WAL files for some time:

- when server-to-server replication is used: while a follower replicates data, it may read from the leader's WAL. Deleting the WAL file on the leader may make the replication fail
- when arangodump is used to create a database dump, it will create a snapshot of data on the server, and the WAL files for that snapshot will be kept around until the snapshot isn't needed anymore (i.e. arangodump finishes).
- the first 180 seconds after server start, all WAL files are intentionally kept, for forensic reasons, and to allow followers to replay events from a leader's WAL when it is restarted. The value of 180 seconds can be changed by adjusting the startup option `--rocksdb.wal-file-timeout-initial`.
- there can be some background processing of changes that may refer to data from WAL files. For example, each insert into a collection will need to increase the collection's `count()` value by 1. To save an extra write into RocksDB on each insert, the `count()` value is only written to the storage engine by a background thread, ideally only once every X insert operations. However, this may lead to WAL files being around for a bit longer, especially if the background thread cannot keep up with the insert workload.

There is the startup option `--rocksdb.wal-archive-size-limit` to put a hard limit on the cumulated size of the WAL files in the archive. From your question, it appears that you are currently using ArangoDB version 3.10.

From the warning message you posted, it seems that the WAL archive cleanup somehow applies the wrong limit values.

It turns out that there has been a recent bugfix, released in ArangoDB version 3.10.1, 3.9.4, and 3.8.8, that should rectify this behavior. So upgrading to one of these or later versions may actually help when using the WAL archive size limit.

Answer (score 0):

Shared your question in the Speedb hive, on Discord, and here is what we got for you:

"By default, ArangoDB set the max_wal_size to 1G the value of rocksdb.wal-archive-size-limit must be set to at least twice this number (otherwise you may end up with a single WAL file and the delete will fail)."

Hope this help, if it doesn't or you have follow up questions, please join the [Speedb Discord](https://discord.com/invite/5fVUUtM2cG) and we will be happy to help.